# Typing Tutor Help C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i m working on typing tutor simple project on C#

[image]

Plz any one help me i have one problem .. i code behind the button

```
private void btnq_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == 81)
        {
            i = Convert.ToInt16(rtb1.Text.IndexOf('q'));

            if (i == 0)
            {

                rtb1.Text = rtb1.Text.Remove(0, 1);
            }

        }
    }
```

when i debug the project and press Q key from keyboard nothing happening ..but when i click Q button with click mouse *(( i write code for mouse click event also but its working ))* it work  and after click now if i press Q button from keyboard then it work ..Why not its work when i first time press key from keyboard..

where i m wrong ? plz help ..i will be wait ..

Comment: Sir Slaks  i m new if any mistak while typing Sorry for that .

Comment: When you click with a mouse the component with the drawn buttons gets the focus - and subsequent keyboard events are intercepted by the component.

Comment: What i should do .? can u Write any example for just one button ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your event handler is attached to the <kbd>Q</kbd> button. What that means is that it will be called only when you press a key *while that button is focused*.

What you should do instead is to add the event handler to the keyboard groupbox, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The component you are  typing in has not the focus when the application starts.

What you can do is to set the focus in it your constructor.

```
MyControl.Focus();
```

Comment: i tried But still same ..after click mouse then keyboard pressed work ..Directly keyboard pressing key not working .kindly explain

Answer (score 0):

i Add this my problem solved but i m still facing one problem .when i start typing, Clock time start and stop with<kbd>Space</kbd> key.what i should do ? its create problem while typing .

```
     private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

    {  
       if (btnclock.Text == "Start")
            e.Handled = false ;
         else
        {
         i = Convert.ToInt16(rtb1.Text.IndexOf(e.KeyChar));

            if (i == 0)
            {

                rtb1.Text = rtb1.Text.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            else
                j++;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString((j));
        }
    }
```